# context free grammar ressource

Tags: grammar, resource-request, online-resources

I am looking for a large...ish context free grammar, preferably in flat format (so no XML for example). The language does not matter. Whether it has features or not doesn't matter either. Can you suggest me a good resource?

## Edit

I am talking about a file.

Comment: any updates on this? The only thing I found is a context-free grammar within the NLTK python toolkit: -> https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ Check #14 If somebody stumbles on this post maybe you can add something.

Answer (score 3):

GPSG, the book (**Generalized Phrase Structure Grammar**, by Gazdar, Klein, Pullum, and Sag) gives a context free psg theory of English which, from the standpoint of syntactic theory, is a great achievement, in my opinion.  It covers all the main parts of English syntax that were analyzed in classical transformational grammar.  It probably would never work as a practical parser, since it was not really intended for that, and it has a *lot* of rules.